# commit one at a time in git

Tags: git

`git add -p` allows you to traverse through each modified file one at a time.

I would like a similar version; however, it needs to allow you to stage one file at a time. I want to be able to stage and provide the commit message as well.

Comment: Your question is very unclear as to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I agree with Andrew.  Do you want to have a separate, per-file message for each file?  Please elaborate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git: Commit multiple files but add messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171022/git-commit-multiple-files-but-add-messages)

Answer (score 5):

I think you need the switch -o for example:

```
git commit -o file1
```

Comment: Yes this is what OP wants, a single command to add and commit a file

Comment: It is possible to list all files you want to commit too using this option. `git commit -o file1 file2 file3` is also permitted ...and this is neither limited to three files only.

Comment: Fun Fact: `git commit -o file1` bypasses `.gitignore`s. Security issue maybe?

Answer (score 3):

So you want to do this?

```
git add <file1>
git commit [-m "message"]
git add <file2>
git commit [-m "message"]
...
```

Comment: @David If you do this in git, the commits are local and can even be tweaked if necessary using `git rebase -i` before anyone else sees them, so there is no need to accomplish all of the above in a single command, if that's what you were worried about. If you really want to do it all in one command, I guess you could write a little script that iterates through the output of some form of `git status`, calling `git add` or `git add -p` on each of them, and then calling `git commit` (without `-m`) to let you specify the message in a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quickie I use to bang through all the modified items from git status.  We do a commit one at a time so I can add comments for each one.

```
for each_git_file in
`git status | egrep 'modified|new file' | awk -F: '{print $2}' | sed 's/[\W\.]*//'`;
 do
     git commit -o $each_git_file;
 done
```